# Android ProgressDialog ends too early

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm running an `AsyncTask` which opens an `HttpConnection` and uses it to download JSON in the `doInBackground` function.

Here is my AsyncTask:

```
    public class AsyncQueryTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String>{
    String jsonString = "";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Getting Ready...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        URL restURL = urls[0];
        try {
            //--------------------------------------------
            // Some initialization
            //--------------------------------------------
            HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) restURL.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlCon.getInputStream();
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A");
            jsonString = scan.hasNext()? scan.next() : "";

            try{
                JSONArray bookArr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                for(int i=0;i<bookArr.length();i++){
                    // Some JSON string processing...
                }

            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Err", "@Activity");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //----------------------------------------------------

            return jsonString;
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And I call it here:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        URL url = // URL for fetching JSON string
        if (/*Some condition*/) {
            //----------------------------------------------
            // Some other tasks
            //----------------------------------------------
            AsyncQueryTask fbqt = new AsyncQueryTask();
            fbqt.execute(url);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
         }
    }
```

As you can see, I initialize the progressDialog properly in `onPreExecute()`, and `dismiss()` it in `onPostExecute()`.

The **problem** is that the progress dialog shows up for only a fraction of a second and it immediately ends, causing the app to transfer to the next activity, without fully performing the tasks it has in the `doInBackground()` section.

What should I do to make the progressDialog last until the `doInBackground()` thread is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of this:

```
 AsyncQueryTask fbqt = new AsyncQueryTask();
 fbqt.execute(url);

 Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

You are lunching the `ProgressDialog` on `LoginActivity` but just after you execute `fbqt` you launch another activity (`NextActivity`) which put the `LoginActivity` on pause cycle, So I guess this closes the dialog!

---

Note: I don't understands your code logic but I think you are trying to launch the `NextActivity` after getting result from `fbqt`, if yes then what you implemented is wrong, you should use Interfaces to get a callback from `AsyncTask` and then launch your `NextActivity`.

Comment: After I execute the AsyncTask, the LoginActivity is already done with, and the next activity should be started. Where should I call the `startActivity()` function if I cant call it after the AsyncTask execution?

Comment: @JeobMallari  but you need to launch `NextActivity` after the asynck task finishes, correct? I mean you want to wait until it is finished then launch `NextActivty`?

Comment: yes I want to wait until after the AsyncTask is done before I launch the next activity

Comment: @JeobMallari okay, I thought that too, just check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43690935/5993410) and you should know how exactly you can do that in a recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

Your way can lead to window leak.
`Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);`
Put the above code in onPostExecute() method.