# Android Development - Get Results of Asyn Task before normal code runs

Tags: javascript, android, listview, asynchronous

I am writing an Android app that loads a list of items into a ListView. The ListView contains an Adapter and a onClick() method to identify which item is selected by the user.

All is well but in the onClick(), I have a call to execute an Async Task which retrieves GPS coordinates form a MySQL Database. Problem is that Async does not complete and the coordinates from the Async is required for the operations that follow.

Inside the onClick() method:

```
new AsyncGetSkipDetails().execute(skipNo);
                                        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + lat + "," + lng);
                                        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                                        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                                        if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                            startActivity(mapIntent);
                                        }
```

This opens up google maps and uses lat and lng to display the location on google maps.

My Async Task:

```
public class AsyncGetSkipDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(PendingOrdersActivity.this, "Please Wait", "Please Wait While Skip Coordinates Are Loaded");
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.isIndeterminate();
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("http://johandrefouche.ddns.net/SG/getskipdetails.inc.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {
            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Append parameters to URL
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("skipNumber", params[0]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            // Open connection for sending data
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";

        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                //StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                line = reader.readLine();


                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (line);

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String line) {
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        tempSkip = line.split("<br>");
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I tried adding a progress bar in order to wait until the lat and lng are returned but does not help.

I did test the Async and does work if I call another method from within onPostExecute().

Any help or advice please? New to Android Development

Comment: see this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43690935/5993410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AsyncTask runs on another thread.  That's the entire point of an AsyncTask-  to run in the background.  If you were to wait for it to finish, there'd be no reason to use one at all.  The correct answer is to put all of the code that needs the result in onPostExecute, and to put up a waiting UI until its done.

Comment: What do you mean by putting all the code in the onPostExecute? Or is there rather another way you can suggest to access a web service that accesses MySQL without using Async task? Reason being it gets the information based on a variable passed to the Async task, and the Async is called only when the user selects a ListView item

Comment: If you have code that uses the result of an sync task, it needs to be called in on pay execute. You can't just put out after the call to execute the task

Comment: Just basicall put the code of diplsaying on Google Maps into the onPostExecute and seems to work fine now.  Thanks.